# How can I detect the number of audio channels in an mp3 in an <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

From what I've read I would expect the following JavaScript code to log "All is well", but instead it hits the error case:

```js
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var ctx = new window.AudioContext();
var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
audio.src = 'http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/tone/files/440Hz_44100Hz_16bit_30sec.mp3';
// As @padenot mentioned, this is the number of channels in the source node, not the actual media file
var chans = source.channelCount;
if(chans == 1) {
  snippet.log("All is well");
} else {
  snippet.log("Expected to see 1 channel, instead saw: " + chans)
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

### What's going on?

Is this, perhaps a CORS issue? Is there some other way to determine that this mp3 file is, in fact, mono?

**Edit:** As @padenot mentioned, this is the number of channels in the source node, not the actual media file

### Clarification

I would love a solution that avoids having to decoding the entire audio file in memeory. `decodeAudioData()`, in my experience, requires decoding the entire mp3 at one, which can take seconds. `createMediaElementSource()` allows you to stream the media and decode as you listen.

Answer (score 4):

A `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` does have a `channelCount` attribute, but it refers to the number of channel of the AudioNode, not of the underlying HTMLMEdiaElement.

Instead, you can decode the buffer, and query its channel count, like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "file.mp3", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function() {
  var cx = new AudioContext() ;
  cx.decodeAudioData(xhr.response, function(decodedBuffer) {
    console.log(decodedBuffer.numberOfChannels);
  });
}
xhr.send(null);
```

And yes, you need CORS headers in the response for this to work.

Comment: Actually, `MediaElementAudioSourceNode.channelCount` is a valid property but does not reflect the number of channels in the media source. [`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode)

Comment: I just tried this in a scratchpad. It's missing `xhr.send(null);` and it should be `decodedBuffer.numberOfChannels`. Then it works.

Comment: `decodeAudioData()` can be very slow on a compressed audio file of any meaningful size. I would much prefer a solution that derives the count without having to decode the entire mp3 in memory.

Comment: Just roll your own JS mp3 parser, it's just a couple bit shifts and offset calculation to determine the channel count.