# How can I determine the number of audio channels in a <video> tag? (HTML5)

Tags: html, audio, video, html5-video

I am wanting to attach an AnalyserNode to each audio channel of a video element so that I can do some audio visualization.

My code works at the moment except that the AudioContext and MediaElementAudioSourceNode both report a channel count of 2 regardless of how many audio channels there actually are in the video.

```
let context = new AudioContext();
let source = context.createMediaElementSource(videoElement);
let srcChannelCount = source.channelCount;  // Always 2!!!
```

In the case I'm testing I have generated a webm file with 1 audio stream containing 8 channels. If I hardcode my srcChannelCount variable to a particular number of channels (e.g. `let srcChannelCount = 8;`) my visualization correctly shows the data for each of the 8 channels, however I'd like the code to detect the number of channels based on the video file.

Can anyone tell me how to determine the actual source audio channel count?

Comment: Will this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835149/how-can-i-detect-the-number-of-audio-channels-in-an-mp3-in-an-audio-tag

Comment: Also note,not all browsers support all features ... and here is one more link, off site: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/462

Answer (score 0):

you can use numberOfChannels property of an audio buffer. You will however need to use decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {} function and xhr request instead of audio element. Example below:

```
function getData( currSource ) {

  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();  
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', currSource , true);  //for example 'sample.ogg'
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        source.buffer = buffer;
        
        console.log('detected '+buffer.numberOfChannels+' audio channels in the selected file');
        }, //end succes        
      
        function(e){
          console.log('error: '+e); //log error
        }
        
        ).catch(error => {
            console.log('failed');
        });
          
      }//end request loaded
  request.send();
}
```